# Compilation error when inheriting Java classes from Kotlin classes using generics

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics, android-room

I am working on an Android project that combines Kotlin and Java (generated code by Android Room library). I was trying to do some generic data access objects.
In Kotlin, this code compiles correctly:

```kotlin
data class Entity(val name: String = "")  
  
interface ExampleBaseInterface<T: Any> {  
    fun foo(): Flow<T>  
}  
  
abstract class ExampleAbstract<T: Any>: ExampleBaseInterface<T> {  
    override fun foo(): Flow<T> = TODO()  
}  
  
abstract class ExampleAbstractList<T: Any>: ExampleBaseInterface<List<T>> {  
    override fun foo(): Flow<List<T>> = TODO()  
}  
  
class ExampleClassList: ExampleAbstractList<Entity>()
```

When using Room library and annotating `ExampleAbstractList` as `@Dao` it generated Java code that looks similar to the following example. It also gives a compilation error without Room, writing the Java class manually.

```java
public class ExampleJava extends ExampleAbstractList<Entity>
```

This code generates the compilation error `ExampleJava is not abstract and does not override abstract method foo() in ExampleBaseInterface`

If I change `foo(): Flow<List<T>>` in the interface it works but my intention is to be able to use `ExampleBaseInterface` receiving both `T` and `List<T>` as the generic parameter like the Kotlin example.

I noticed that with pure Kotlin it works, and also with pure Java code including the same generics structure it also works, wondering why when combining Kotlin generics + Java children it does not work.